# Why am I obtaining this error message retrieving objects from a JSON file after this FormArray changes in my reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, javascript-framework

I am working on an Angular project using reactive form and introducing **FormArray** (beacause I have a situation where a field is dinamically created as multiple fields) I am facing the following problem.

Basically into a form defined my HTML code I have something like this:

```
<div class="col-10">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let commessa of commessaList.controls; index as idx">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'error':commessa.invalid && commessa.touched}"
                 [formControlName]="idx"
                 class="form-control" id="commessa">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button type="button" *ngIf="idx===0" (click)="addCommessaField()" class="btn btn-success"
        [ngClass]="'pad'"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

      <button (click)="deleteCommessaField(idx)" *ngIf="idx!==0" class="btn btn-danger">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </ng-container>

    </div>
</div>
```

This section is used to define the hightlighted section of my form (where I can add multiple "Commessa" fields:

[image]

Then into my TypeScript code I have defined the **orderForm: FormGroup;** object that I use to define the form fields and the related validation rules, I set this into the **ngOnInit()** method:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.orderFormValues = new OrderFormValues();

    console.log("orderFormValues VALUES: " + this.orderFormValues.statoOrdine);

    this.orderForm = this.fb.group({
    idOrdine: [null, [Validators.required]],
    dataInserimentoOrdine: [new Date(), [Validators.required]],
    statoOrdine: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    //commessa: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    commessaList: new FormArray([
    new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
    ]),

    CIG: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$")]],
    dataInizioAttivita: [null, [Validators.required]],
    dataFineAttivita: [null, [Validators.required]],
    referente: [null, [Validators.required]],
    ruoloReferente: [null, [Validators.required]],
    tipologiaDiPartecipazione: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    quotaPercentualeDiRTI: [null, [Validators.max(100)]],

    cliente: [null, [Validators.required]],
    vatCliente: [null, [Validators.required]],
    clienteFinale: [null, []],
    vatClienteFinale: [null, []],

    tipologiaContratto: [null, []],
    importoContratto: [null, [Validators.required]],
    linkContratto: [null, [Validators.required]],
    dataSottoscrizioneContratto: [null, [Validators.required]],

    nomeSocieta: [null, [Validators.required]],
    vatSocieta: [null, []],
    buName: [null, [Validators.required]],

    presenzaAQ: [false, [Validators.required]],
    linkIdentificativoAQ: [null, []],
    accordoQuadro: [null, []],
    residuoAccordoQuadro: [null, []],
    compagineDiAQ: [null, []]

    });



    this.ordersService.getAllOrders().then(orders => {
        this.orders = orders;
        console.log("RETRIEVED ORDERS: ", orders);
        this.loading = false;
    });

        .........................................................................................
        .........................................................................................
        .........................................................................................
}
```

As you can see into the **FormGroup** defintion the section related to the multiple "Commessa" field is defined as **FormArray** in this way:

```
commessaList: new FormArray([
    new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
]),
```

For completeness I add that then in my TypeScript code I also have these two methods used to insert the value inserted by the user in the multiple **Commessa** fiels in this **FormArray** object:

```
addCommessaField() {
    this.commessaList.push(new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]));
}

deleteCommessaField(index: number) {
    if (this.commessaList.length !== 1) {
        this.commessaList.removeAt(index);
    }
    console.log(this.commessaList.length);
}
```

As you can see in the previous code snippet into my **ngOnInit()** method I am performing also this call to an **OrderService** object:

```
this.ordersService.getAllOrders().then(orders => {
    this.orders = orders;
    console.log("RETRIEVED ORDERS: ", orders);
    this.loading = false;
});
```

This call simply retrieves a list of orders (at the moment mocked into a JSON file) that are displayed in the homepage and here I am obtaining a strange error.

The code of my **getAllOrders()** service method is simply this one:

```
getAllOrders() {
    return this.http.get<any>('assets/json_mock/ordini.json')
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => <Order[]>res.data)
    .then(data => { return data; });
}
```

As you can see it retrives and return orders from this **ordini.json** file.

The problem is that calling the **getAllOrders()** service method it retrieve the orders list but in the Chrome console I am also obtaining this error message:

```
core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '0'
    at _throwError (forms.js:3576)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:3398)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:7679)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:8451)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:8368)
    at FormControlName.wrapOnChangesHook_inPreviousChangesStorage (core.js:26966)
    at callHook (core.js:4730)
    at callHooks (core.js:4690)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4630)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.js:9748)
```

The strange thing is that it happens after that I implemented this multiple "Commessa" fields using the previous **FormArray** (before I had only a single "Commessa" input field and I had not this error). I suspect that maybe the error could be in my original JSON content but I am not understanding why and how I can solve this problem.

Following the content of my **ordini.json** file:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,

      "referente": {
        "name": "Mario",
        "surname": "Rossi",
        "complete_name": "Mario Rossi",
        "role": "Operation Manager",
        "avatar": "mario-rossi.jpg"
      },

      "company": {
        "name": "TEST S.p.A.",
        "VAT": "IT 03318271214",

        "BU": {
          "name": "Digital Solution",
          "code": "DS"
        }
      },

      "dettaglio_ordine": {
        "data_inserimento": "08/08/2020",


        "commessa": {
          "code": "AAA0001"
        },

        "identificativo_contratto_hyperlink": "LINK-ID-CONTRATTO-TEST",
        "tipologia_contratto": "ORDINE",
        "presenza_AQ": true,
        "identificativo_AQ_hyperlink": "LINK-AQ-TEST",
        "accordo_quadro": 12,
        "importo_contratto": 122000,
        "residuo_AQ": 20000,
        "compagine_di_AQ": "COMPAGINE-DI-AQ-TEST",
        "quota_percentuale_di_RTI": 20,
        "tipologia_di_partecipazione": "GARA PUBBLICA",
        "cig": "CIG-TEST-1",
        "cliente": "CLIENTE-TEST-1",
        "vat_cliente": "VAT-CLIENTE",
        "cliente_finale": "CLIENTE-FINALE-TEST-1",
        "vat_cliente_finale": "VAT-CLIENTE-FINALE",
        "data_sottoscrizione_contratto": "8/12/2020",
        "data_inizio_attivita": "8/28/2020",
        "data_fine_attivita": "8/31/2020",
        "stato_ordine": "CHIUSO"
      }
    },

    {
      "id": 2,

      "referente": {
        "name": "Mario",
        "surname": "Rossi",
        "complete_name": "Mario Rossi",
        "role": "Operation Manager",
        "avatar": "mario-rossi.jpg"
      },

      "company": {
        "name": "Blabla S.p.A.",
        "VAT": "IT 03318271214",

        "BU": {
          "name": "Cyber Security",
          "code": "CS"
        }
      },

      "dettaglio_ordine": {
        "data_inserimento": "09/08/2020",


        "commessa": {
          "code": "AAA0002"
        },

        "identificativo_contratto_hyperlink": "LINK-ID-CONTRATTO-TEST",
        "tipologia_contratto": "ORDINE",
        "presenza_AQ": false,
        "identificativo_AQ_hyperlink": "LINK-AQ-TEST",
        "accordo_quadro": 12,
        "importo_contratto": 122000,
        "residuo_AQ": 20000,
        "compagine_di_AQ": "COMPAGINE-DI-AQ-TEST",
        "quota_percentuale_di_RTI": 20,
        "tipologia_di_partecipazione": "GARA PUBBLICA",
        "cig": "CIG-TEST-2",
        "cliente": "CLIENTE-TEST-1",
        "vat_cliente": "VAT CLIENTE TEST",
        "cliente_finale": "CLIENTE-FINALE-TEST-2",
        "vat_cliente_finale": "VAT-CLIENTE-FINALE-TEST",
        "data_sottoscrizione_contratto": "8/12/2020",
        "data_inizio_attivita": "8/28/2020",
        "data_fine_attivita": "8/31/2020",
        "stato_ordine": "CHIUSO"
      }
    },

    {
      "id": 3,

      "referente": {
        "name": "Francesco Nicola",
        "surname": "Romano",
        "complete_name": "Francesco Verdi",
        "role": "Operation Manager",
        "avatar": "francesco-romano.jpg"
      },

      "company": {
        "name": "Blabla S.p.A.",
        "VAT": "IT 03318271214",

        "BU": {
          "name": "Cyber Security",
          "code": "CS"
        }
      },

      "dettaglio_ordine": {
        "data_inserimento": "10/08/2020",


        "commessa": {
          "code": "AAA0002"
        },

        "identificativo_contratto_hyperlink": "LINK-ID-CONTRATTO-TEST",
        "tipologia_contratto": "ORDINE",
        "presenza_AQ": false,
        "identificativo_AQ_hyperlink": "LINK-AQ-TEST",
        "accordo_quadro": 12,
        "importo_contratto": 122000,
        "residuo_AQ": 20000,
        "compagine_di_AQ": "COMPAGINE-DI-AQ-TEST",
        "quota_percentuale_di_RTI": 20,
        "tipologia_di_partecipazione": "GARA PUBBLICA",
        "cig": "CIG-TEST-3",
        "cliente": "CLIENTE-TEST-3",
        "vat_cliente": "XXX123",
        "cliente_finale": "CLIENTE-FINALE-TEST-3",
        "vat_cliente_finale": "YYY321",
        "data_sottoscrizione_contratto": "8/12/2020",
        "data_inizio_attivita": "8/28/2020",
        "data_fine_attivita": "8/31/2020",
        "stato_ordine": "CHIUSO"
      }

    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see here in the objects defined in this JSON file the **commessa** field is defined in this way:

```
"commessa": {
    "code": "AAA0002"
},
```

maybe is wrong or maybe the problem is elsewhere.

What am I missing? Why am I obtaining this error? How can I try to fix this bug?

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9251)

Comment: `.then(res => <Order[]>res.data)` you try to convert the whole json file to `Order array` type, try without `<Order[]>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the **formArrayName** div in html.

Make sure to enclose the HTML with the ***formArrayName="commessaList"***

```html
<div formArrayName="commessaList">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="commessa" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Commessa</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let commessa of commessaList.controls; index as idx">
        ................
        ................
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget use a getter?

```
get comessaList()
{
   return this.orderForm .get("comessaList") as FormArray
}
```

To avoid initial errors, you can use a *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="orderForm" [formGroup]="orderForm">
....
</div>
```